# Prove or disprove: If $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is a matrix and it's columns are basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$..

Tags: linear-algebra

then it's rows are basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.


I encountered this question and I answered wrong, and here's what I did: 
I took a counter example: $A = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}_{2\times 3}$. 
the columns $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$, and they're a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, but the rows aren't a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. 
Now I can't understand what's wrong with my counter example and why this is true. 
I would appreciate it if someone can point out my mistakes and why my example doesn't work, and why the sentence is true. 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: The columns of your matrix  are $\ \pmatrix{1\\0}, \pmatrix{0\\1},$ *and*  $\ \pmatrix{0\\0}\ $.  Since they're linearly dependent, they don't constitute a basis of $\ \mathbb{R}^2\ $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true because your matrix $A$ has to in fact be square.

If the columns of $A$ are a basis for $\Bbb{R}^m$, then $A$ has $m$ linearly independent columns. But there are actually $n$ columns so it follows $m=n$.
Now recall that the column rank (which is $m$) is equal to row rank so there are $n$ linearly independent rows of $A$. They form a basis for $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

The linearly independent columns are those columns with leading $1$'s when the matrix is brought into $RREF$. Thus if the columns form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$, then necessarily there must be $n$ vectors, and so $m = n$.

For $m=n$ then the $RREF$ of $A$ is $I_{n\times n}$, the columns and rows are a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Every basis of $\mathbb R^m$ consists of exactly $m$ vectors. Why do you consider $m>n$?

Comment: No, the statement is true for all $m,n$. But only when $m=n$ the columns can form a basis of $\mathbb R^m$. If $m\neq n$ the statement is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).